# Stop vertical scroll

Tags: html, css, scroll, fixed, absolute

I need to prevent a div from scrolling vertically, but allow it to scroll horizontally...
basically add "vertical position:fixed" and "horizontal position:absolute"
I would prefer to do it with CSS or JavaScript...
This is the div i need to fix vertically...

`#logo{
    z-index: 50;
    top: 16px;
    margin:0px auto 0px auto;
    -webkit-filter: invert(100%); 
    position: absolute;
    width: 124;
    height: 56;
}`

Thank you very much

Comment: can you add the relevant code so far and a jsfiddle example??

Comment: Or disabling vertical scroll in just that div... that would also work

Comment: Not really possible with CSS, but you could do it with JavaScript.

Comment: @TylerH how is it possible with javascript? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've just added a container div with position:relative and changed the logo div position to fixed, and it worked...
thanks anyway for your help everybody!

```
#container{
height: auto;
width: 76%;
position: relative;
top:0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin: auto;
}

#logo{
z-index: 50;
top: 16px;
margin:0px auto 0px auto;
-webkit-filter: invert(100%); 
position: fixed;
width: 124;
height: 56;
}
```

best regards